# Bash: Length of array with variable name

Tags: bash, shell

I have filled an array `foo$i` with values and have set `i=4` (but `i` could be anything). How can I get the length of this array? The command `${#foo4[@]}` works, but `${#foo$i[@]}` doesn't. How can I find the length if the name of the array has a variable?

Comment: Didn't I just answer this for you in a comment on a different question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With bash 4.3, there's a new feature, namerefs, which allows this to be done safely:

```
i=4
foo4=( hello cruel world )
declare -n foo_cur="foo$i"
foo_count=${#foo_cur[@]}
echo "$foo_count"
```

Prior to bash 4.3, you need to use eval [(despite its propensity for causing bugs)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048):

```
i=4
foo4=( hello cruel world )
eval 'foo_count=${#foo'"$i"'[@]}'
echo "$foo_count"
```

...yields the correct answer of `3`.

Comment: Of course. You could, for instance, substitute `"$(eval 'echo ${#foo'"$i"'[@]}')"` somewhere within a larger command. That said, subshells introduce inefficiency, so using them without cause is silly.